# How could I receive cURL Error 14077410 on one subdomain, but not another?

Tags: php, curl

I am running a script that involves the use of cURL. I have two subdomains that I run the script on, both hosted on the same server, and it works on one subdomain but not the other.

It works exactly as desired on subdomain A, but on subdomain B I get the error message "cURL Error #:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure".

From my research I've seen most people suggested the cURL version needs to be updated to a version > 7.40, but my version is 7.42 and I don't think it could be the case since it works on subdomain A. So, I am kind of at a loss because I can't find any other info.

Here is the cURL code in question, although it is exactly the same on both subdomains so I'm not sure the code could be the problem...

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://api.zipwhip.com/user/login",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "username=##########&password=****",
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);
echo $response;
curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
}
```

I hope I'm not missing something obvious here, but any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subdomains were using different versions of PHP. Found and made that change and it works fine. Hope this can help someone else.